# "No content available via JSON " in Java - Iphone Communication

Tags: java, iphone, spring

I have used  "Apache mina service" to write web service for Iphone .
I get my requests correctly and I am able to send responses too..

But I get this excepion running always in my console " No content available via JSON "

Can anyone tel me the reason ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is there is no JSON reaching at device side in turn of your request made at the server.

Have you tried checking the server console after making request to the server via iphone. If you have put log in your server side for the data being sent or request received, You could see what JSON is being send at the device end for the request.

I hope it'll definitely solve your issue.

awaiting for the response.

Comment: I have  put SOP on the server side tat is java side ... To that sop I get the values printed.. BUt for tha caught exception (JSONMAPPING exception I get the below)                                                  .org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: No content available via given JsonParser
 at [Source: java.io.StringReader@b80017; line: 1, column: 1]
 at org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:153)

Comment: Sorry I forgot to use the jackson-all-1.6.4.jar .... 
But the problem now is that I get java.io.EOFException: No content to map to Object due to end of input exception

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777746/why-does-json-objectmapper-throw-java-io-eofexception-no-content-to-map-to-obje

Comment: I hope you could be able to solve your problem using above links.